# Redefine \textsc for slightly large small caps

Tags: macros, typography, scaling, small-caps

In most fonts, the small caps are as tall as the x-height, but this looks weird when you want to tack an 's' onto the end of an abbreviation to make it plural (discussed in depth on [typophile](http://typophile.com/node/40920)).

I can create a new command `\textmc` (for *moyen* caps) to do this easily:

```
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\newcommand{\textmc}[1]{\textsc{\scalefont{1.1}#1}}
```

But I'd prefer to just redefine `\textsc`.  The approach that I was taking, however, seems to give me an infinite loop as it flips back and forth between defintions:

```
\newcommand{\oldtextsc}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\oldtextsc{\scalefont{1.1}#1}}
```

Any advice on how to redefine a command which calls the original definition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A straightforward way is to use `\let` to store the current definition of `\textsc`.

```
\let\oldtextsc\textsc
\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\oldtextsc{\scalefont{1.1}#1}}
```

(See [Patching existing commands](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-patch) from the TeX FAQ for details.)

However, this can fail if `\textsc` happens to be in some place that gets written in the aux file (a section title, for instance), so a safer version is

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldtextsc}{\textsc}
\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\oldtextsc{\scalefont{1.1}#1}}
```

(see the documentation of `letltxmacro` for more information).

The problem is that `\textsc` is a "robusted" command, so that LaTeX will write a special form of it in the aux file; something like `\section{\textsc{a}}` would result in LaTeX writing

```
\textsc  {\scalefont  {1.1}a}
```

and when interpreting it for the table of contents this would become

```
\oldtextsc{\scalefont{1.1}\scalefont{1.1}a}
```

and eventually to a scaling factor of 1.21.

Comment: There is a problem in this redefinition if `\textsc` happens to be written in the `.aux` file: `\textsc{a}` would become `\textsc{\scalefont{1.1}a}` which would result in a scaling factor of 1.21.

Comment: @egreg My answer was mainly about `\let` and didn't touch the substance of the OP's definition. Please point out any changes needed (or feel free to edit my answer).